# Java ArrayList Date variable Sorting?

Tags: java

I want my List will be sorted on the basis of `Date` variable so i have to write this logic

```
public  static void main(String a[]){
        AuditLogComponent comp = new AuditLogComponent();
        List<TableRecord> records = new ArrayList<TableRecord>();
        LogFolderRecord log = new LogFolderRecord();
        Date date = new Date();
        Timestamp fromTS1 = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        log.setStampDate(fromTS1);
        records.add(log);
        Date date1 = new Date();
        Timestamp fromTS2 = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());
        LogFolderRecord log1 = new LogFolderRecord();
        log1.setStampDate(fromTS2);
        records.add(log1);
        records.add(new LogPeopleRecord());

        comp.columnsList(records);
    }
```

And how i am calling Sort method of List

```
public void columnsList(List<TableRecord> records){

          Collections.sort(records, new StampDateComparator());
        for(TableRecord record : records){
            Table table = record.getTable();
            Field[] fields = table.fields();
            for(Field field : fields){
                field.getName();
                record.getValue(field);

            }
        }

    }
```

And my Comparator class is

```
public class StampDateComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object object1, Object object2) {

        try {
            Method method = object1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getStampDate");
            Date value = (Date) method.invoke(object1);

            Method method1 = object1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getStampDate");
            Date value1 = (Date) method.invoke(object2);

            if(value != null && value1 != null )
            return  value.compareTo(value1);;
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        return 0;

    }
```

But it not throwing exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.comp.macro.StampDateComparator.compare(StampDateComparator.java:22)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
```

What is exact way to do Sorting on the basis of Date?

Comment: you need to implement `comparator<tablerecord>` and not `object`

Comment: Take help from this. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/

Comment: Why use reflection? Why not simply use generics as they are suppose to be or cast to the appropriate type (after checking)?

Comment: Its not possible for me TableRecord is Interface and Classes like LogPeopleRecord,FolderPeopleRecord,FamilyRecord etc.

Comment: Because its a JOOQ implementation of my code

Comment: @fvrghl Is it a duplicate? This question is in fact about reflection in my opinion.

Comment: Yes it not duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

Your `Comparator` class should look like

```
public class StampDateComparator implements Comparator<TableRecord> {

    @Override
    public int compare(TableRecord record1, TableRecord record2) {
        return record1.getStampDate().compareTo(record2.getStampDate());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Even if `TableRecord` is an interface, you can still use it in your `Compartor`, all your implementation of `TableRecord` should have the method `getStampDate` correctly implemented.

Comment: Tablerecord Does not contain StamDate its a Interface

Comment: then you need to revisit your design, and then understand why you wouldn't want to have `getStampDate` in your `TableRecord` interface. Because it doesn't makes sense to put some random objects in your `List`

Comment: TableRecord Interfaces given by JOOQ API its not my class and its not random object its implements TableRecord class

Answer (score 0):

In `Comparator` class, at first you need to get `Timestamp` from `TableRecord` class. `Timestamp` has its `compareTo` method to sort it. Design your `StampDateComparator` class like:

```
public class StampDateComparator implements Comparator<TableRecord> {

    @Override
    public int compare(TableRecord record1, TableRecord record2) {
        Timestamp timestamp1=record1.getStampDate();        
        Timestamp timestamp2=record2.getStampDate();
        return timestamp1.compareTo(timestamp2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the method signatures of `getDeclaredMethod` and `invoke` are wrong:

```
Method method = object1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getStampDate", null);
Date value = (Date) method.invoke(object1, null);

Method method1 = object2.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getStampDate", null);
Date value1 = (Date) method.invoke(object2, null);
```

They require the parameters for the method. See JavaDoc:

- [Class#getDeclaredMethods(String name, Class... parameterTypes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)
- [Method#invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: If this is wrong it should give Compile time exception to me

Comment: what jdk are you using?

Comment: could you please try if my code works? i don't get, why you don't get a compilation error

Comment: I made a mistake i called this object1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getStampDate"); two time while it would Object2 also method varaible creating issue that also resolved

Comment: but the class of `object1` and `object2` should be the same so that doesn't matter

Comment: Hmm but now its working i am not getting exception also same code without adding null argument its working to me